# Batch ticket modification on Phabricator

Tags: pm-software

I have many old tickets with open status on **Maniphest** which are completely useless now.

How can I change the status of all of them to 'resolved' without changing one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a batch edit feature.  You can access it on any search.

- Go to the Maniphest application
- Use the advanced search (or a saved search) to get the old tasks that you want to remove
- Select all the tasks that you want to remove by pressing the shift button and clicking them one by one (there is a "Select All" button as well)
- Click "Batch Edit Selected"
- At the bottom, select the "Change Status" action and select the desired new status.
- Click "Update Tasks"

WARNING: There is no "Undo" button.  Once this is done, the only way to undo it is to try to repeat this process and change the status back or go one by one.